# How to pass values/variables between tabs?

Tags: jquery

**Setup:**

I am using JSPs and jQuery. There is a 'parent' page which holds 3 tab-pages. On tab 1, there is a form where user have to fill few fields like first name, last name, etc. The user fills the form and moves on to other tabs. On tab 3, I have to show the course name which he entered on tab 1. So essentially I have to pass values between tabs.

**Problem:**

I can access some of the fields from tab 1 on tab 3, like I have a drop down on Tab 1:

```
            <div class="dropDownMenu">
                <select id="states">
                    <option value="ca">CA</option>
                    <option value="ny">NY</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

I can access this on Tab 3 like:

```
alert($('#states').text());
```

Bur I cannot access "course_id" on tab 3. Tab 1 has this:

```
            <div class="myCourse">
                <label for="course">Course</label>
                <input type="text" name="course_name" id="course_id" value=""/>
            </div>
```

I want to access **course_id** on tab 3.
Can somebody tell me how to do this? I am pretty much newbie to jQuery/Ajax, so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: (offtopic) you should use `<label for="course_id">Course</label>`
`

Comment: are all the tabs on the same page?

Comment: @Sagivo: yes, all tabs are on the same page.

Comment: i posted you a comment how to do that. hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind an event that on `tabselect` we write the value of `course_id` to our location on tab 3.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UdSUp/4/

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});

$('#tabs').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
    $("#showCourseID").text($("#course_id").val());
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jonathan. I will give it a try. And I guess this code will go in the 'parent' tab, right?

Comment: @Learner nope, just place it after where you declare the ".tabs();" I edited my answer to help.

Answer (score 0):

if you need the value just try

```
$("#course_id").val();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sagvio. I have already tried this. It returns blank.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the value of course_id. Value is what gets set by an input field, thats why text wasn't working.

```
$('#course_id').val();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply AJak. I have already tried this. It returns blank.

Comment: if you call alert($('#course_id').length);​ does that give you 1? just making sure the element exists when you try to call val()

Comment: Hm, not sure whats going on without being able to look at things more. I've made a simple Fiddle to show how val() works, hopefully it helps you out. Only other thing I can think of is the val() is getting cleared out between tab 1 and 3 or is never set. http://jsfiddle.net/gMkZk/